# SQL Server Delete query execution timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Statistic table with about 2 000 000 records and I need to delete record which are older than one month.

While executing DELETE query below I get Time Out error. Can it be related with Indexes? I am not sure where is the problem and how to solve it.

```
DELETE FROM Statistic WHERE (DateStamp < DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
```

I am also adding execution plan

[image]

Image url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfh6k.png

Comment: You could try adding a nonclustered index on DateStamp.

Comment: From where (what tool to execute the query) are you getting the time out error?

Comment: @BerndLinde SQL Server management studio

Comment: Mind showing the exact error please, I have run SQL commands in SSMS that ran for hours (and once more than a day)

Comment: Your plan shows a lot of time being used in sorting.  I'm not sure, but that may be it trying to rebuild indexes? Also the query in your execution plan window doesn't match the query in your question (your picture shows a query for everything a month in the future).

Comment: @Becuzz Yes, the plan executed with +1 month but actually I need -1 month but that doesn't change anything. The problem still exists.

Comment: Updating indexes is the main slowdown, but that doesn't explain why the query would fail, it's not a large table.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the planned execution plan that you provided, the main time spent is on updating the indexes (preparing the table, sorting the data and re indexing them) after deleting all the data. The delete itself is running quickly.

I would recommend that you have a look at the possibility to drop all the indexes on `Statistic` (except for `IX_DateStamp` since that will be used by your delete command and `PK_dbo.Statistic` since that looks to be your primary key index) before doing the delete and then recreating them after the delete command has finished.

Remember that if you will be dropping the indexes, any query in a production database environment that attempts to retrieve data from `Statistic` while those indexes are dropped, will be extremely slow. So this might need to be scheduled as part of a maintenance windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
DELETE 
FROM Statistic 
WHERE PK IN (
            SELECT PK
            FROM Statistic WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE (DateStamp < DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
            )
```

Comment: the PK is the column name of the column that is referenced in the clustered index

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a clustered index (I can't tell if you do), disabling the clustered index will make the whole table inaccessible and you would not be able to run a DELETE on the table anyway. It would fail with:

> The query processor is unable to produce a plan because the index ...
>   is disabled.

If you're deleting (or inserting) more than 10% of the table, you should remove all of the non-clustering indexes, delete the records, then rebuild the non-clustering indexes.

If you're deleting less than 10% of the table, leave the indexes in place.